# How to amend an existing python file

Tags: python

I am trying to ammend a group of files in a folder, by adding F to the 4th line (which is number 3 in python, if I'm correct). With the following code below, the code is just continuously running and not making the amendments, anyone got any ideas?

```
import os

from glob import glob


list_of_files = glob('*.gjf')  # get list of all .gjf files

for file in list_of_files:

    # read file:
    with open(file, 'r+') as f:
      lines=f.readlines()
      for line in lines:
          lines.insert(3,'F')
```

Comment: `lines=f.readlines()` completely detaches the data from the file. Now it's just a regular list contained in Python. No modifications to that list will therefore be reflected in the file. You need to write the output back out

Comment: @roganjosh so after the last line 'lines.insert(3,F)' what is the best way to write the output back into a gjf file?

Comment: I don't actually know the format of `gjf` so I'm hesitant to say exactly and I can't seem to find a decent spec. But there are plenty of tutorials online for writing files. From what I gather and how you read the file, I assume it's just an extension and a regular `.txt` file in reality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for file in files:
    # read your file's lines
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()

    # add the value to insert in the list of lines at index 3
    # don't forget line-break (\n)
    lines.insert(3, 'F\n')

    # join lines to create a string
    text = ''.join(lines)

    # don't forget to write the string back in your file
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to edit a file with Python in this way. You would need to create a temporary file and then do some cleanup at the end by renaming the temporary file and removing the temporary file. The core logic is to read through the original files and add an `F` to the 4th line, otherwise just add the line. This can be done with a function like this:

```
import os

def add_f_4th_line(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        with opne('temp', 'w') as f_out:
            for line_number, line_contents in enumerate(f_in):
                if line_number == 3:
                    f_out.write(line_contents.replace('\n', 'F\n'))
                else:
                    f_out.write(line_contents)
    os.rename('temp', filename)
    os.remove('temp')
```

`enumerate` will keep make an iterator of the line number and the contents of the line, so just iterate over each line, and you can find the 4th line with `line_number == 3`. Then, it will take that line and replace `\n` with `F\n`. `\n` is a new line character, so I'm assuming the end of the line is this character. So after adding this function, you'll just need to call this function for each file you get with your `glob` call.

```
import os

from glob import glob


list_of_files = glob('*.gjf')  # get list of all .gjf files

for file in list_of_files:
    add_f_4th_line(file)
```

Comment: They don't want every 4th line, they want just the 4th line